# Integer parts of multiples of irrationals

Tags: number-theory, analysis, irrational-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, set-partition

Let $\alpha>0$ and define 
$$S(\alpha)=\big\{\lfloor n \alpha \rfloor: n\in\Bbb Z^+ \big\}.$$ Here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$ and $\mathbb Z^+$ the set of positive integers.

**Question.** *Is it possible to find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$, such that*

$$
S(\alpha)\cap S(\beta)= S(\beta) \cap S(\gamma) =S(\alpha)\cap S(\gamma) = \varnothing\text{?}
$$

It is well-known that the following holds
$$
S(\alpha)\cap S(\beta)=\varnothing\quad\,\text{and}\,\quad S(\alpha)\cup S(\beta)=\mathbb Z^+
$$
if and only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational (and positive) and $\,\,\dfrac{1}{\alpha}+\dfrac{1}{\beta}=1$.

**Update 1.** According to a 1995 Putnam examination question, there are no $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ for which $S(\alpha)$, $S(\beta)$ and $S(\gamma)$ form a partition of $\mathbb Z^+$.

**Update 2.** The following result holds:

$S(\alpha)\cap S(\beta)=\varnothing$ *if and only $\alpha,\beta$ are irrational and if there exist positive integers $m,n$, such that*
$$
\frac{m}{\alpha}+\frac{n}{\beta}=1.
$$

This is Theorem 8 in:
[Th. Skolem, *On certain distributions of integers in pairs with given differences*, Math. Scand., 5 (1957) 57-68.](http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/math/article/viewFile/10490/8511)

Comment: This was on the 1995 Putnam exam, according to a comment on an answer to OP's question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151533/numbers-with-disjoint-sets-of-multiples-of-integer-parts

Comment: 1995 Putnam Problem B6 asks to prove the three sets cannot partition $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, and this has easier solution.

Answer (score 9):

Using the known fact, we see that
$S(\alpha)\cap S(\beta) = \varnothing $
If we have
$$\frac{k}{\alpha}+\frac{l}{\beta}  =1 $$
for some positive integers $k, l$

Conversely, we use Kronecker's theorem ( If $1$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the set $\{((n\alpha), (n\beta)) : n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$ is dense in $[0,1]^2$) , and [detailed analysis](https://www.csun.edu/%7Esungjin/sample3.pdf) in case when they are linearly dependent over rationals, we obtain that the condition above for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is indeed holds when $S(\alpha)\cap S(\beta)=\varnothing$.

On the other hand, from the link above (by Lemma 1) we can also deduce that if $\alpha$ rational, then $S(\alpha)\cap S(\beta)\neq \varnothing$ regardless $\beta$.

Hence, we have

(**Theorem**) $S(\alpha)\cap S(\beta) = \varnothing $ if and only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational numbers satisfying $$\frac{k}{\alpha}+\frac{l}{\beta}  =1 $$
for some positive integers $k, l$

If $S(\alpha)\cap S( \beta)=\varnothing$, and $S(\beta)\cap S(\gamma)=\varnothing$, then
there are positive integers $k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4$ such that
$$\frac{k_1}{\alpha}+\frac{k_2}{\beta}=\frac{k_3}{\beta}+\frac{k_4}{\gamma}=1$$

If $k_2\neq k_3$, then we have
$$\frac{k_1k_3}{\alpha}-\frac{k_2k_4}{\gamma}=k_3-k_2$$
In this case, $S(\alpha)\cap S(\gamma)\neq \varnothing$.

If $k_2=k_3$, then we have
$$\frac{k_1}{\alpha}=\frac{k_4}{\gamma}$$
This case also, $S(\alpha)\cap S(\gamma)\neq \varnothing$.

Hence, we have proved that for real numbers $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$,
$$
S(\alpha)\cap S(\beta)= S(\beta) \cap S(\gamma) =S(\alpha)\cap S(\gamma) = \varnothing 
$$
is impossible.